# ArrayList to Access Methods in Classes

Tags: java, class, arraylist

Is it possible to create an ArrayList that contains new instances of a Class and then use that ArrayList to access methods in the given class? Here is an example to make it more clear:

```
ArrayList<myOtherClassName> myClassObjects= new ArrayList<myOtherClassName>();
myClassObjects.add(new myOtherClassName());
myClassObjects.indexOf(1).methodInOtherClass();
```

This, however, doesn't work!
Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: You should not use class as an identifier, it is a reserved word in Java. I'm modifying it to myClassObjects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
ArrayList<myOtherClassName> class1 = new ArrayList<myOtherClassName>();
class1.add(new myOtherClassName());
class1.get(0).methodInOtherClass();
```

You need to:

- call .get() method instead of .indexof()

indexof method returns the index, and not the value/object from the list.

Also, Always write

```
List<myOtherClassName> class1 = new ArrayList<myOtherClassName>();
```

instead of

```
ArrayList<myOtherClassName> class1 = new ArrayList<myOtherClassName>();
```

ArrayList is a implementation of List, you should ALWAYS create object of type interface rather than of the implementation class.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use class as variable.

`indexOf()` will return an integer. Use `get()` instead

```
ArrayList<myOtherClassName> mylist = new ArrayList<myOtherClassName>();
mylist.add(new myOtherClassName());
mylist.get(0).methodInOtherClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Oliver-R...

```
Try Below Code 

ArrayList<myOtherClassName> myClassObject = new ArrayList<myOtherClassName>();
myClassObject.add(new myOtherClassName());
myClassObject.get(0).methodInOtherClass();

the method methodInOtherClass() return type is void it will not return any thing other
```

Comment: How do you know that "the method methodInOtherClass() return type is void it will not return any thing other" :). Its his class and method.

Comment: your calling in that some class method,so you know  what is the return type of that method

Comment: But, where is the method where you see int or void as the return type?